# How to do image transformation after scaling in fabricjs?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

When the scale of an image changes, it's transformation isn't possible until you click on it. And, you could also move the image even from outside of the rectangular boundary of the image. That's weird.

After the moment the image scale changes, i should be able to transform the image without a click on the image. How to do it ?

```
test = function(type){
var obj = activeobj[0].getBoundingRect().height;

if(type === 'fb'){
this.image.set({
  scaleX: 0.5,
  scaleY: 0.5
 });
 canvas.renderAll();
} else {
 this.image.set({
  scaleX: 0.25,
  scaleY: 0.25
 });
 canvas.renderAll();
 }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hazeebp/2z9yb1nd/43/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [object.setCoords()](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#setCoords) to set the corner coordinate of object.

Here is updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2z9yb1nd/48/)

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.setHeight(400);
canvas.setWidth(400);
let image;
// Left Image
fabric.Image.fromURL(`http://www.qygjxz.com/data/out/248/3979080-wallpaper-xperia.png`, (img) => {
  img.set({
    left: 0,
    stroke : 'red',
    strokeWidth : 20,
    id:'wallpaper',
    top: 0
  });
  image = img;
  img.scaleToWidth(300);
  img.scaleToHeight(300);
  canvas.add(img).setActiveObject(img);
})

var activeobj = canvas.getObjects();

test = function(type){
  if(type === 'fb'){
   image.set({
    scaleX: 0.5,
    scaleY: 0.5
    });
  } else {
    image.set({
    scaleX: 0.25,
    scaleY: 0.25
    });
  }
  image.setCoords();
  canvas.requestRenderAll();
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Plus" onclick="test('fb')">
<input type="button" value="Minus" onclick="test('insta')">
<canvas id="c"> </canvas>
```